# Cannot play DVDs after installing Linux 22.04

Tags: apt, vlc, dvd, aptitude

I tried to play DVDs on the Videos package. I got the following error:
[image]

Despite several attempts installing, removing and reinstalling restricted extras and vlc (both with apt and aptitude) I still cannot play DVDs (although CDs play OK so it is obviously not an audio issue). My latest attempts were as follows:

1. installed aptitude
2. typed sudo aptitude install vlc in command terminal
3. typed aptitude search vlc (all the vlc files that should be there seem to be installed (showing "i" at beginning of entry) but I'm not sure out of the list what indications from the resultant list would indicate a problem i.e some files which look like duplicates or "development" versions are preceded with "p" for not installed)
4. typed aptitude search libdvd (All the libdvd files that should be there seem to be installed but again I don't have the knowledge to know for sure)
5. created a log file in vlc. When I tried playing DVD, the log file was 124 lines long but I couldn't pinpoint the specific problem which would allow me to troubleshoot - I'm just not knowledgeable enough to know what I'm looking for
6. I tried to play DVD again - VLC just closed without warning

Can anybody suggest further steps before I do a whole reinstall of Ubuntu 22.04 OS?

Comment: rather than VLC have you tried just using the default app `videos`? ISTR VLC issues in 20.04 between the snap and deb versions. Both versions are available in 22.04

Comment: I tried to use videos initially, but that was giving me errors. This was specifically why I tried to install vlc - as an alternative dvd player that might actually work. After installing vlc and it still not working, I deleted videos as I thought this might be part of some kind of conflict. Wrongly, as it turns out.

Comment: what errors? perhaps [edit] your question accordingly rather than just add to the comment trail.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at this: [https://help.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html.en](https://help.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-help/video-dvd-restricted.html.en) Other info from Ubuntu: [https://help.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-help/video-dvd.html.en](https://help.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-help/video-dvd.html.en) This article previously helped me out too: [https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/](https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/) Hope this helps!